# How to identify gaps in a sequential list using Django templates

Tags: django, templates

If I have an ordered sequential list in my django template:

```
my_list = [
    (1, "Billy Holiday"), 
    (2, "Louis Armstrong"), 
    # Number 3 is missing!
    (4, "Ella Fitzgerald"),
    (5, "Frank Sinatra"),
]
```

And I want to show something like this in my html:

```
1. Billy Holiday
2. Louis Armstrong
-- Some rows may be missing --
4. Ella Fitzgerald
5. Frank Sinatra
```

Is there a clever way to do this? I'm trying to accomplish this using Django templates. The idea would be to look at the previous iteration of the loop, and identify if rows are missing based on the counter values.

Comment: you would need to use jinja2 instead of django templates or do it in the view

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you try to move some logic from views to templates. I would strongly advise against this approach. It is not testable, harder to maintain, most likely will conflict with DRY principle.

So just doing the work in the view would probably be better.

However, if you are totally adamant that you want this done in template, you can make your own template filter:

**someapp/templatetags/app_tags.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def set_missing_items(collection):
    new_list = []
    last = 0
    for item in collection:
        if item[0] != last + 1:
            new_list.append('-- Some rows may be missing --')
        new_list.append(item)
        last = item[0]
    return new_list
```

And then use it as follows:

**template.html**

```
{% load app_tags %}
{% for item in list|set_missing_items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endif %}
```

Make sure to follow all steps from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) to make your custom filters work (like having proper folder structure with __init__.py files, making sure that app that has those filters is installed, etc).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a simple approach will be build the list this way:

```
my_list = [
    (1, "Billy Holiday"), 
    (2, "Louis Armstrong"), 
    (3, ""),
    (4, "Ella Fitzgerald"),
    (5, "Frank Sinatra"),
]
```

and write a if for take care of the blank data inside the loop.